# Missing any kind of lights?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl3

I am trying to make my first 3D game in OpenGL with Shaders (LWJGL3)
I read and follow a lot of tutorials but can't figure it out what kind of light I am missing here? The wall doesn't get any effect from the light

[image]

It is supposed to be like this one:
[image]

And my point light part in fragment:

```
vec4 calcLightColour(vec3 light_colour, float light_intensity, vec3 position, vec3 to_light_dir, vec3 normal)
{
    vec4 diffuseColour = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vec4 specColour = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Diffuse Light
    float diffuseFactor = max(dot(normal, to_light_dir), 0.0);
    diffuseColour = diffuseC * vec4(light_colour, 1.0) * light_intensity * diffuseFactor;

    // Specular Light
    vec3 camera_direction = normalize(-position);
    vec3 from_light_dir = -to_light_dir;
    vec3 reflected_light = normalize(reflect(from_light_dir , normal));
    float specularFactor = max( dot(camera_direction, reflected_light), 0.0);
    specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, specularPower);
    specColour = speculrC * light_intensity  * specularFactor * material.reflectance * vec4(light_colour, 1.0);

    return (diffuseColour + specColour);
}

vec4 calcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 position, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 light_direction = light.position - position;
    vec3 to_light_dir  = normalize(light_direction);
    vec4 light_colour = calcLightColour(light.colour, light.intensity, position, to_light_dir, normal);

    // Apply Attenuation
    float distance = length(light_direction);
    float attenuationInv = light.att.constant + light.att.linear * distance +
        light.att.exponent * distance * distance;
    return light_colour / attenuationInv;
}
```

Comment: What "effect" are you expecting the light to have on the wall? Can you describe what you expect to see in more detail? Also, it would help to know what lights you already have in the scene.

Comment: I just added another pic (was taken from my blender). And I am only using point light

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you diagnose this without more information. How have you set up the scene in OpenGL? Are you using shaders or the older, deprecated fixed-function pipeline?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using shaders and I just added my point light parts in fragment

Comment: @ThaiDoanNam are *actually* calling those two functions? You should add the *relevant* code, (like both the vertex and pixel shader for example). Right now, you just provided us with two functions, in the fragment shader. We don't know which values you passed in as parameters, where you are calling them, *if* you are calling them, which uniforms you are setting and so on.